# Can't apply Label.delete function

Tags: pine-script

I tried using label.delete function:

```
if (longsignal and showpos)
l3 = label.new(time + 10*dt, low, xloc=xloc.bar_time, text = 'SL='+tostring(longsl), color=#02ad09, style=label.style_labelup, textcolor=color.white, size=size.normal)
label.delete(l3[1])
```

But i have this error:

```
Undeclared identifier 'l3'
```

I even tried to add ":= "after "l3" instead of a "=" but stil get different error:

```
Mismatched input 'l3' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'.
```

I suspect it has to do with IF condition i used before label creation.... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring the variable in the local scope, this could cause the issue.

In the example below the label variable is declared in the global scope, then use `:=` to re-assign the value in the local scope.

```
var label l3 = na
if (longsignal and showpos)
    l3 := label.new(time + 10*dt, low, xloc=xloc.bar_time, text = 'SL='+tostring(longsl), color=#02ad09, style=label.style_labelup, textcolor=color.white, size=size.normal)
    label.delete(l3[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

lines inside the condition must be shifted by 4 spaces or 1 shift

```
if (longsignal and showpos)
    l3 = label.new(time + 10*dt, low, xloc=xloc.bar_time, text = 'SL='+tostring(longsl), color=#02ad09, style=label.style_labelup, textcolor=color.white, size=size.normal)
    label.delete(l3[1])
```

when the condition is met for the first time there is no label l3[1]